# Datatable Ajax Validation

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

Get the result from API and return the result in JSON and show in another file with data table ajax. Sometimes API not working and it returns false or error in the alert. My question is how do we set validation in data table ajax? If API doesn't respond then they give set an alert. How can we set the alert in data table ajax?

My code is.

```
$('#playeraction').DataTable( {
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": false,
       "ajax": {
           "url": 'daily_action.php',
           "type": "POST",
           "dataSrc": "results"
       },
    "columns": [
       { "data": "country" },
       { "data": "city" },
       { "data": "zipcode" },
       { "data": "currency" },
       { "data": "gender" },
       { "data": "Birthday" },
       { "data": "status" },
       { "data": "RegistrationDate" },
       { "data": "FtdDate" },
       { "data": "Deposit" },
       { "data": "TotalDeposit" },
       { "data": "Cashout" },
       { "data": "TotalCashout" },
       { "data": "Bonuses" },
       { "data": "Revenue" },
       { "data": "Chargeback" },
       { "data": "ReverseChargeback" },
       { "data": "SideGamesBets" },
       { "data": "SideGamesWins" },
       { "data": "JackpotContribution" },  
       { "data": "playerid" }
       ],
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax - you can pass in any options which you would be able to pass to jquery's $.ajax() function directly, so you should be able to define an "error" callback (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for details), e.g.

```
"ajax": {
  "url": 'daily_action.php',
  "type": "POST",
  "dataSrc": "results",
  "error": function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
    alert("An error occurred when loading data");
    console.log("data loading error: " + jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText + ". Observe the request in the browser's Network tab for more detail.");
  }
},
```